# A question on a theorem about polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am having trouble proving this theorem:

> For a field $k$, let $f \in k[x]$ be
>   irreducible, and $g \in k[x]$ be a
>   polynomial. Let $h\in k[x]$ be an
>   irreducible factor of $f\circ g$. Show
>   that $\deg f \mid \deg h$.

My attempt so far was to prove this:

> Let $\mathrm{Sq}(n,k)$ be the set of
>   square $n\times n$ matrices with
>   entries in $k$. Let $A\in
> > \mathrm{Sq}(n,k)$ which has an
>   irreducible characteristic polynomial
>   $f\in k[x]$. Let $g \in k[x]$. Then
>   there exists a $B\in \mathrm{Sq}(n,k)$
>   satisfying $A=g(B)$ iff $f\circ g$ has
>   a factor in $k[x]$ of degree $n$.

And here's my proof.

> **Proof.** ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $B$ exists and let $p$ be the minimal polynomial
>   of $B$. Since $k[B]$ contains $k[A]$,
>   $\deg p = n$. Since $f(g(B)) = f(A) =
> > 0$, we have $p \mid f\circ g$.
>
> ($\Leftarrow$) Let $h\mid f\circ g$ and
>   $\deg h = n$. Let $C$ be the companion
>   matrix of $h$. Then $f(g(C)) = 0$, and
>   since $f$ is irreducible with $\deg f = n$,
>   $g(C)$ is similar to the companion matrix of $f$. Therefore
>   $g(C)$ is similar to $A$. As such, $A = T^{-1} g(C) T$
>   for some $T\in\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$. Then
>   $g(T^{-1}CT)=A$, so $B=T^{-1}CT$. $\blacksquare$

I'm not sure where to go from here. Is this even relevant? Is there a better way to go about this? Hints would be helpful, a proof even more appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $h$ is an irreducible factor of $f \circ g$. Let $L = k(\alpha)$ for some root $\alpha$ of $h$ then $\dim_k (L)=\deg(h)$. Notice that $h(x) \mid f\circ g(x)$ so $\alpha$ is also a root of $f\circ g$ and so $g(\alpha)$ is a root of $f$.

Since $\beta=g(\alpha) \in k(\alpha)$ then $F=k(\beta)\subseteq L$. So to finish the proof $\deg(h)=[L:k]=[L:F][F:k]=[L:F] \deg(f)$.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: +1, but the fourth (and last) line should start with $deg(h)=...$ instead of $deg(g)=...$.

Comment: @elgeorges : fixed it, thanks